# Backbone.js collection fetch request missing data parameter in IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js, internet-explorer-9

So, I've used Backbone.js to write a messaging system. It works fine in Chrome and FF but IE9 has issues with a particular fetch call that kills it. (I'm working in MVC3).

I have a poll that checks for new messages coming in, which sends the date to the server. The poll is called with this method:

```
DoMessageFetch = function() {
    var now = new Date().toUTCString();
            Chat.mymessages.fetch({
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    Now: now
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    // if there are messages ...
                    // for each message, open a chat window
                    if (Chat.mymessages.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < Chat.mymessages.length; i++) {                            
                            var useridto = Chat.mymessages.at(i).get("UserId");
                            var name = Chat.mymessages.at(i).get("ScreenName");
                            // a chat-window with this useridto is NOT on the page
                            if (!($('#chat-window-' + useridto).is(':visible'))) {
                                Chat.doChatMessageFetch(name, useridto, null); // this constructs a Backbone view
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function () { console.log('ERROR: fetching general poll messages failed.'); }
            });

            Chat.mymessages.reset();
}
```

In IE9 the Now param is null when I watch breakpoints in my Controller. This means the request follows the wrong code path on the server...

I don't understand where my Now parameter went in IE. Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to the different behaviour of

```
new Date().toUTCString()
```

between IE , Google Chrome and Firefox.

For example the result in Chrome is :

```
"Thu, 20 Sep 2012 20:19:15 GMT"
```

while in IE you will get

```
"Thu, 20 Sep 2012 20:19:15 UTC"
```

MVC3 ModelBinder will ignore IE Format and leave your Now parameter null.The solution to this problem is to replace

```
new Date().toUTCString()
```

with

```
new Date().toJSON()
```

The only thing to note with this solution is that it will not work by default on IE7 due to the lack of the toJSON() function but this problem can be solved using Douglas Crockford [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library which is also recommended when using Backbone.js

Comment: You are right, thanks for clarifying my suspicion...I decided to refactor and go with actionIds instead of checking date in Controller. IE made me write better code :o